# An enum that is not a sub of Enum?

Tags: java, enums

The method `getDeclaringClass()` of [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) class is looking up first whether the enum value is an enum value, i.e., it's super is [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html). If not, returning the super-class of whatever the class the given instance was born to:

```
public final Class<E> getDeclaringClass() {
    Class<?> clazz = getClass();
    Class<?> zuper = clazz.getSuperclass();
    return (zuper == Enum.class) ? (Class<E>)clazz : (Class<E>)zuper;
}
```

How can an instance that the `getDeclaringClass()` method runs on can NOT be an `instanceof` the `Enum` class?
An enum type can not be extended, so the only super-class of an enum class is `Enum`.

So - in the following example:

```
public enum Dirs {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST 
}
```

`Dirs` is a sub-class of `Enum`. However, `Dirs` can not have a sub-class itself -- it can't be extended.
`getDeclaringClass()` of anyone of the four directions -- like `NORTH.getDeclaringClass()` is `Dirs`, which is `NORTH.getClass()`.

The source code of `getDeclaringClass()` suggests that there can be cases that `NORTH` here can have a superclass other than `Enum`. i don't see how this can happen.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

More specifically:  How can there be a case that `NORTH.getDeclaringClass()` will **NOT** return `NORTH.getClass()`, which is `Dirs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not entirely true, that you can't extend your own enum class. For example in case of

```
enum Dirs {

    NORTH {
        @Override
        public Dirs getOppositeDirection() {
            return SOUTH;
        }
    }, 
    SOUTH {
        @Override
        public Dirs getOppositeDirection() {
            return NORTH;
        }
    };

    public abstract Dirs getOppositeDirection();
}
```

`Dirs` is actually `abstract` class, and its enum values `NORTH` and `SOUTH` are implementations of this class which provide body of abstract `getOppositeDirection` method, which means that they extend `Dirs`.

So if you will call

```
System.out.println(Dirs.NORTH.getDeclaringClass());
System.out.println(Dirs.SOUTH.getDeclaringClass());
System.out.println(Dirs.NORTH.getClass());
System.out.println(Dirs.SOUTH.getClass());
```

You will see as output something like

```
class yourPackage.Dirs
class yourPackage.Dirs
class yourPackage.Dirs$1
class yourPackage.Dirs$2
```

which means that `getClass` will return actual class which implements this enum, while `getDeclaringClass` will return enum itself.

BTW: Enum doesn't need to be abstract to let you provide specific implementation to some method by accepting extention of enum. You can also do something like

```
enum MyEnum {
    FOO {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo";
        }
    },
    BAR{
        public String toString() {
            return "baR";
        }
    };
}
```

and `BAR.getDeclaringClass()` will return `MyEnum`, while result of `BAR.getClass()` will be `MyEnum$2`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that your enum has behaviour, then each instance can have it's own implementation.

```
public enum Dirs {
    NORTH {
      public Point move(Point p) { return p.move(0, 1); }
    }, 

    SOUTH {
      public Point move(Point p) { return p.move(0, -1); }
    }, 

    EAST {
      public Point move(Point p) { return p.move(1, 0); }
    }, 

    WEST {
      public Point move(Point p) { return p.move(-1, 0); }
    }

    public abstract Point move(Point p);
}

class Point{
    private final int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
    public Point move(int dx, int dy) { return new Point(x + dx, y + dy); }
}
```

Now

```
assert Dirs.NORTH.getClass() != Dirs.SOUTH.getClass();
```

while

```
assert Dirs.NORTH.getDeclaringClass() == Dirs.SOUTH.getDeclaringClass();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe that you got downvoted because your code wouldn't compile with standard `java.awt.Pont` class, while it is correct for implementation I provided in edit. Hope you don't mind that I changed your post a little.

Comment: Oh, I provided the code just for the illustration of the subclassing in enum, the actual `move` method together with the `Point` class are absolutely arbitrary. Probly should remove my answer, as the accepted answer is similar.

Comment: Since your answer is correct I don't think you should delete it, but that is not mine decision.